# php://output results in empty file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress theme template file in use by a page. The template queries the db for an array and then attempts to output the result to a csv file. No output to the browser is expected. Here is code:

```
/***
 * Output an array to a CSV file
 */
function download_csv_results($results, $name = NULL)
{
if( ! $name)
{
    $name = md5(uniqid() . microtime(TRUE) . mt_rand()). '.csv';
}

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. $name);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header("Expires: 0");

$outstream = fopen("php://output", "w");

foreach($results as $result)
{
    fputcsv($outstream, $result);
}
fclose($outstream);
}
```

The file is written to the user's downloads directory as expected, but it is empty. I've debugged to verify there is a result of 117 elements. The loop above is executing. It's as though the output buffer is not being flushed or is being cleared by Wordpress.

Comment: Have you tried with the `ob_`functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try to use :

```
$outstream = fopen("php://output", "a");
```

instead of :

```
$outstream = fopen("php://output", "w");
```

Comment: Thanks Phenix. Unfortunately, the result is the same though.

Comment: Did you try with fwrite() instead of fputcsv() ?

Comment: Thanks. fwrite does the trick. I just needed to format the array output to have commas and quotes as needed.